# Web page is not responsive across mobile device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have made an existing site to responsive using twitter bootstrap. When I check the responsiveness by resizing the browser **it works fine** and perfectly fit in the viewport window. But when I check the site across mobile and tablet it does not work and show the default desktop layout. I have used `meta viewport tag` and respond.js But It does not work anymore. I can not understand why the site does not resonsive in specific mobile device.

Can you help me out from this issue? I can not preview the code in here, because I can not understand where is the problem exactly.

My demo site: [**playbox**](http://ronysatiar.com/playbox/index.html)

Comment: you have 2 metas named `viewport`, remove the second one on the line with `<meta content="width=1024" name="viewport">` - http://screencast.com/t/1dirqNCgj

Comment: Thanks! The issue is fixed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of

```
<meta content="width=1024" name="viewport">
```

set

```
<meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">
```

Remove second one width=1024 and you'll be good to go :)

Comment: Oops! I didn't see it before. BTW, thanks for your awesome support. It's now working!